# is it possible for cssh to use the .ssh config file?

Tags: ssh, config

Trying to figure out if it is possible for cssh to resolve the aliases in my ~/.ssh config file so that my /etc/clusters file can then just use the aliases ? Have not been able to get it to work

```
/etc/clusters cluster = alias1 alias2
~/.ssh/config  Host alias1 etc.
```

Comment: did you happen to find the answer?